# Spring boot Kafka messaging. How to use SpEL to manage handler access

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-el

I'm using Kafka in Spring Boot project. There are a lot of benefits in case you have simple flow (to use `@KafkaListener`, `@KafkaHandler`) and spring prepares almost everything for development.

In my application I have different handlers for the same message data. I want to use SpEL to manage handlers manipulating header data, but I've not detected corresponding API for that.

So my question: is it possible to manage my handlers via `SpEL` in case I have special headers for that (Header for example `"X-OPERATION_TYPE":"patch"`)? How?

### P.S.

I can make workarounds using GoF Strategy as example, but I hope spring already has solution for that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such a "conditional routing" in Spring for Apache Kafka, but you can do that routing manually in the single `@KafkaListener` with plain `if...else` or `switch`.

For more comprehensive routing logic it would be better to take a look into Spring Integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html